# Parse JSON array inside an object in T-SQL

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have a json array like this:

```
{
    "TagsDictionary": [
        { 
            "key" : "property1",
            "value" : "property1Value"
        },
        {
            "key" : "property2",
            "value" : "property2Value"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to query it in T-SQL. I want this result:

```
property1      | property2
property1Value | property2Value
```

I read [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15). But I can't achieve result with my structure. Unfortunately the JSON is stored in the database and I can't change it, because other modules depends on it.

I'm using SQL Server 2016.

Comment: Does this JSON contain only two items in the `"TagsDictionary"` JSON array?

Answer (score 3):

Not 100% sure this is what you are looking for

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,JSON varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'{"TagsDictionary": [{"key" : "property1","value" : "property1Value"},{"key" : "property2","value" : "property2Value"}]}')


;with cte as (
Select A.ID
      ,RN  = row_number() over (partition by id,Indx order by B.[Key])
      ,CN  = Indx+1
      ,B.[value] 
From  @YourTable A
Cross Apply (
                Select Indx = B.[key]
                      ,C.[key]
                      ,C.[value] 
                 From  OpenJSON(A.JSON) A
                 Cross Apply OpenJSON(A.Value) B
                 Cross Apply OpenJSON(B.Value) C
            ) B
) 
Select *
 From  cte
 Pivot ( max(value) for CN in ([1],[2]) ) pvt
```

**Returns**

```
ID  RN  1               2
1   1   property1       property2
1   2   property1Value  property2Value
```